# Python broken after 15.10 to 16.04 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, 15.10, python

After doing an upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04, my Python packages seem broken. Looks like a compilation error for python-minimal.

```
me@me:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython-dbg libpython-dev libpython-stdlib python
Suggested packages:
  python-doc python-tk
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython-dbg libpython-dev libpython-stdlib python
4 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1208 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/160 kB of archives.
After this operation, 113 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up python-minimal (2.7.11-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/compileall.py", line 16, in <module>
    import struct
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/struct.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _struct import *
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_struct.so: undefined symbol: _Py_RefTotal
dpkg: error processing package python-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where it came from, but I had a python binary in /usr/local/bin that was overriding my default one. It was build with an older gcc and that was causing the problem.

Comment: That means you had compiled and installed Python from source in the past.